# Mysql query is not using any key

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST` (
`ID1` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
`ID2` mediumint(8) NOT NULL default '0',
`DATE` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 UNIQUE KEY `COMBO_INDEX` (`ID1`,`ID2`),
 KEY `ID2` (`ID2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB`
```

This table has approx 16196496 records

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ID1 IN ('8518582',  '5398912',  '6120243',  '6841316',  '7580078',  '7671953',  '7775737',  '7792470',  '7887985',  '7888375',  '7946516',  '8008760',  '8111722',  '8211235',  '8262746',  '8365675',  '8396853', '8399818',  '8410062',  '8459079',  '8490683')
```

I am getting output as

```
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TEST                   | ALL  | ID1           | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16196496 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I don't understand why the query is not using any key.

Also, when I run this query in this innodb table, it's taking huge amount of time 329 second (MySQL version 5.0.45-log).

While if I run same query on myisam table, it's taking just 2 seconds (though on explain its showing the same result). I am using MySQL version 5.5.

Why is the query not taking any key?

Comment: What if you remove quotes around **numbers**? PS: why there is no primary key in this table?

Comment: Yes in that case its taking index , but it doesn't make any sense.
I have many other similar tables and i using same query where its using index normally

Comment: sometimes mysql behaves not predictable on implicit type casts. So it's always a good idea to use the same data type as the original column is. It's that rare case when instead of casting the constant operand mysql casts the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure but another reason which i though is "it might be case when there is insufficient memory available for indexes to load and hence full scan"

Answer (score 1):

`innodb` needs a primary key to fast seek to the row found in index. As long as you don't have any - mysql cannot do that so it prefers fullscan.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html

> Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the index search leads directly to the page with all the row data. If a table is large, the clustered index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to storage organizations that store row data using a different page from the index record. (For example, MyISAM uses one file for data rows and another for index records.)

So the obvious solution - is to replace the unique key with a primary key (though personally I don't like natural primary keys, composite natural primary keys especially).

PS: seems like my guess in the comments about using numbers instead of strings helped. Though the advice about adding primary keys still in action - do that to get even better performance.

Comment: If that's the case , then when i remove quotes , why its working fine

Comment: @chicharito: in that case mysql don't need to perform an implicit cast. I haven't experienced this thing much - because I always specify the data in the appropriate type. So I haven't investigated the *real* roots of the issue, sorry.

Comment: @chicharito: added the question to the temporary bookmarks to see if this will happen (though I doubt so ;-)